# Context-free Grammar for a Context-free Language Intersecting a Regular Language (get the Maximum Number of Rules)

Tags: regular-language, descriptive-complexity, context-free-languages

It is well known that the intersection of $L \cap R$ of a context-free Language $L$ and a regular Language $R$ is context-free. Each proof I have seen constructs a automaton (a PDA) that accepts $L$ and one (a DFA) that accepts $R$. Than a further automaton (a PDA) is constructed that accepts $L \cap R$. This automaton can be converted to a context-free language.

Is there some literature that gives a proof without constructing automatons and constructs a context-free grammar that generates $L \cap R$ directly?

What I want to know actually: Given a context-free Language $L$ and a regular Language $R$. How many rules at most does a context-free grammar need to generate $L \cap R$?

Comment: If I may, I am curious as to why you asked that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer to your first question http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/cfg.pdf.

A summary of the proof given in the link. First, it is shown that proving $L \cap R$ is CFL reduces to proving that $L \cap R'$ is CFL, where $R'$ is a regular language recognized by a DFA with exactly one final state. Then from the grammar for L (in Chomsky normal form) and DFA for R' a new grammar for $L \cap R'$ is constructed using a few straightforward rules.

Comment: Could you please include some more details to make the answer more self-contained?

Comment: Tanks! This is what I was looking for :-)

Comment: Added a summary of the proof to make it more self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classical cross-product construction, originally published
by Bar-Hillel, Perles and Shamir (1961) in `On formal properties of
simple phrase structure grammars.`It can be found in most elementary
books on automata theory. (the reference to the initial paper appears in the paper suggested by @Jurij, which I could not access as I wrote this answer).

Actually, it can be done with any CF grammar, no normal form being
required (but ... see below).  On the FSA side, any recognizing
finite-state automaton will do, including non-deterministic.

The complexity is $O(n^{p+1})$ for both the construction time and the
size of the resulting grammar, where $n$ is the number of states of the
automaton and $p$ is the length of the longest rule right-hand side of
the grammar.

Hence, reducing the grammar in Chomsky normal form (CNF) will give $n=2$ and
allow for cubic time and space (and result size) complexity. More precisely, some of the constraints of CNF are not even needed. It is enough to put it in 2-form, by introducing new non-terminal so that no right-hand side containt more than 2 symbols.

The size of the resulting grammar can be
further reduced by minimizing the finite automaton.

[Minimizing a DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) has a time complexity $O(ns \ log\ n)$, where $n$ is
the number of states and $s$ is the size of the alphabet. However
the cost is much higher for a NDFA, as it is $O(2^n)$. There is no
escape from that if you have a NDFA to begin with, since this high
cost is needed for [determinizing the NDFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinization) which requires a powerset construction on the set of states.